# Omitting dummies in panel regression?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, panel-data, stata, intervention-analysis

I am running a regression studying the effects of different interventions (which appear as dummy variables - they either did or did not have that particular intervention). I don't have a control group - I have set it up as a pre-/post-, comparing this group's medical expenditures before and after said interventions. I have it set up as panel data, with time 0 and time 1.

At time 0, nobody would have any intervention - every dummy variable would be zero.

At time 1, everybody will have had one of the interventions (this is basically a pre-/post- on the same group of people).

If this wasn't panel data, I'd normally omit one of the dummies - e.g., with five interventions, I'd include Int1, Int2, Int3, and Int4, but exclude Int5 which would become the reference category, and Int1 through Int4 results would be interpreted as relative to Int5.

But because at time 0 every single person has a 0 in each of these dummy variables - I can include all 5 interventions, because they can all use that time 0 as the reference category, right?

Comment: So you only have two observations per group (i.e., pre/post)? Do any individuals receive multiple interventions?

Comment: Yep, just two per group, and nobody receives multiple interventions.

Comment: How are the interventions different? Do they vary in their intensity?